# Custom object to tableview swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I am binding my custom class object to a table view but its showing me nothing

```
class car{
 var carName:String = ""
 var carModel:String = ""
 var carPic:String = ""
}
```

in my controller

```
var cars = [car]();
```

fill the object with coredata in viewdidload()

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SearchTableViewCell;
                let row = cars[indexPath.row];
        print(carName)

        cell.carNameLabel.text = row.carName
        return cell;
    }
```

i am able to see the carName in my console correctly, but when i look into the view its showing me nothing its empty, but i am able to perform all my actions on selection row event.

I thought it might be due to constraints, but if i bind this table view with some array its showing me properly data on UI.

Comment: It looks like the contents of SearchTableVIewCell will be needed to have any idea why this is not working. Could you please add it?

Comment: Show us how you're building the table of cars. I.e. if in response to network request, are you calling `tableView.reloadData()` when you're done populating the array? Also, by the way, you'd generally want to follow Cocoa naming conventions and start class names with uppercase letter (e.g. `Car`).

Comment: for var i = 0; i < 10; i++ {
            var car = car();
            car.carName = "Name " + String(i)
            car.carModel = "Testing"
            self.cars.append(car);
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData(); even binding this way is unable to see anything on UI.

Comment: Did you set the `dataSource` and `delegate` of the tableView? You can do this in either IB or programmatically. Make sure your `UITableViewDataSource` methods are getting called at all. Also make sure your `numberOfRowsInSection`Is returning `cars.count`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are printing to the console appears to be incorrect.

Your statement `print(carName)` is not accessing your array of `cars`.

Try adding `print(row.carName)` to debug your problem.

If you are getting the correct output in the console then that means

```
cell.carNameLabel.text = carName
```

should add the correct value to your label.

However, it doesn't appear correct to me based on the code that you are showing since I'm not able to see `carName` as coming from the data in your `cars` array.

You should also show something like

```
class SearchTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var carNameLabel: UILabel!
}
```

in your code so we can be sure that the label exists.

Also, as a tip about naming, class names should start with an upper case letter. It is a convention practiced by Apple and most iOS developers.

Comment: Sorry printing mistake, i am doing in same way as you have written, when i print row.carName is printing current name in debugger, but still not able to see anything in my tableview.

Comment: What happens if you hardcode a string like `cell.carNameLabel.text = "some car name"`? That will determine if your label can show the text.